# I want to use props to pass a variable to view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Here is the view. I really want to pass this varialbe tmp_sell to here, but still out of luck, would you mind anyone skilled to have a look for my view code below:

```
    <p @tmp_sell="getTmpSell" >?</p>
    <input ref="q_subtotal" placeholder="Subtotal" @tmp_sell="getTmpSell"  id="q_subtotal"   />
export default{
props: ['tmp_sell'],
}
```

This is the componet with the varialbe I want

```
choosenProductSell(ev, p, i){

   var tmp_one_sell = parseFloat(d.data().p_sell);   
   this.tmp_sell = this.tmp_sell + tmp_one_sell;
},
```

I really declare the varialbe on both side, but I think I missing something `this.tmp_sell` to allocate to view. Please let me know how can I allocate to input tag `q_subtotal`.

Comment: It's kind of hard to make sense of what you're asking for. If it's just the bare, basic input binding, you should start by reading through https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html to see how input binding works.

Comment: `choosenProductSell` is not a component, but just a JS function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not enough to clarify you problem. You should try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

But even this small piece of code has some problems.

1. The `<input>` tag with @tmp_sell="getTmpSell" cannot work, since input cannot produce custom `tmp_sell` events.
2. You define the `tmp_sell` as props: ['tmp_sell'] but bind on event. It looks like you are confusing `v-bind`(:) with `v-on`(@)

I would also suggest you to put more effort in learning of Vue.js basics, like Daniel already said in the comment above.